# Data Factory Slice Starts

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that needs to run daily... but the data only arrives at around 2pm on that day (for the previous day)... so when midnight ticks over, the data isn't available, and therefore everything falls over ;)

I have tried this:

```
"start": "2016-02-10T15:00:00Z",
"end": "2016-05-31T00:00:00Z",
```

but it still kicks off at midnight, I assume because I have my scheduler is as follows:

```
"scheduler": {
    "frequency": "Day",
    "interval": 1
},
```

i think i need to use either anchordatetime, or offset.. but i'm not sure which?

Answer (score 2):

Following in pipeline just means that you want pipeline enabled during that period.

```
"start": "2016-02-10T15:00:00Z",
"end": "2016-05-31T00:00:00Z"
```

Following in activity definition means that you want the activity to run at the end of the day, thus, midnight in **UTC time**.

```
"scheduler": {
    "frequency": "Day",
    "interval": 1
},
```

If you want the activity to kick off at 2pm, use following

```
"scheduler": {
    "frequency": "Hour",
    "interval": 24,
    "anchorDateTime": "2016-02-10T14:00:00"
},
```

You should make it consistent in target dataset definition as well.

```
"availability": {
    "frequency": "Hour",
    "interval": 24,
    "anchorDateTime": "2016-02-10T14:00:00"
}
```

Hope that helps!!